# Python requests Module. SSL Cert Verification bug

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, client-certificates

I'm trying to use the requests module to make a post request to an endpoint that requires ssl auth.  My pem file is in the specified path and contains the client cert, and private key.  However, I keep getting the Certificate Verified Failed exception.  I see in the nginx logs that the request never even made it there.  Anyone have any ideas why? I know the certs should work.

```
params = {    
          "param_2" : "32100",
          "param_1" : "abc"
          }

headers = {
           "Content-Type" : "application/json"
          }
body = json.dumps(params)

r = requests.post(
                  https://somesite.com/somepath,
                  data=body,
                  headers=headers,
                  timeout=10,
                  verify="/path/to/cert.pem"
                  )

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./somefile.py", line 264, in <module>
    start()
File "./somefile.py", line 149, in start
    verify="/path/to/cert.pem"
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 448, in    request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 554, in send
   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 417, in send
   raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the requests docs:

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
>   verify to False.
>
> > > > requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
>
> By default, verify is set to True. Option verify only applies to host
>   certs.
>
> You can also specify a local cert to use as client side certificate,
>   as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or
>   as a tuple of both file’s path:
>
> > > > requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/server.crt', '/path/key'))

So it seems like you've just got the args wrong. Try it with 'cert' instead of verify.

Comment: verify=False might not be what you want.. there's kind of no point to using SSL if you're not validating certs.